# Add a SOAP Envelope to an XML in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I´d like to add a soap envelope to a XML using groovy and XMLParser.

This is my code

```
    import groovy.xml.XmlParser

    def soapEnvelope = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Header>
        </soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>"""

    def incomingRequest = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ns1:login xmlns:ns1="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
        <ns1:username>DemoUser</ns1:username>
        <ns1:password>DemoPass</ns1:password>
    </ns1:login>"""

    def parsedSoapEnvelope = new XmlParser().parseText(soapEnvelope)
    def parsedIncomingRequest = new XmlParser().parseText(incomingRequest)

    // Add the content of the incoming request to the existing SOAP body

    parsedSoapEnvelope.'soapenv:Body'[0].appendNode(parsedIncomingRequest)

    // Convert the modified SOAP envelope to a string
    def newXmlString = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(parsedSoapEnvelope)

    println newXmlString
```

But I´m getting the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:login xmlns:ns1="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"/>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

No sons inside login node :(

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Expecting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:login xmlns:ns1="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
            <ns1:username>DemoUser</ns1:username>
            <ns1:password>DemoPass</ns1:password>
        </ns1:login>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use append instead of appendNode

change : parsedSoapEnvelope.'soapenv:Body'[0].append(parsedIncomingRequest)

append(groovy.util.Node) takes Node where as appendNode(java.lang.Object) takes object. [image]